# Check if parallel execution is happening in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-unittest, concurrent.futures

I have the following code, which uses selenium to open 10 google search pages and do a search all 10 searches at the same time.

I think it runs correctly (in parallel), but I'm not sure, because it actually seems to open 5 instances of the browser at a time (however, this might be to do with just the gui opening I guess).

Would love to know if this is truly running in parallel, or whether I need to use the cores in the CPU as well (if this can be done?)

test.py

```
import unittest
from testsss import Testsss
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class Runner():

    def parallel_execution(self, *name):

        suite = unittest.TestSuite()

        for method in dir(Testsss):
            if (method.startswith('test_selenium')):
                print('testing')
                suite.addTest(Testsss(method))

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            list_of_suites = list(suite)
            for test in range(len(list_of_suites)):
                test_name = str(list_of_suites[test])
                executor.submit(unittest.TextTestRunner().run, list_of_suites[test])

Runner().parallel_execution(Testsss)
```

Testsss.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest
import time

class Testsss(unittest.TestCase):
    print('ok3')
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
    @staticmethod    
    def selenium_test(self, testno):
        print('ok4')
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://google.com")       
        search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
        search_field.send_keys("Test " + str(testno) )
        search_field.submit()
        print("ok1")

    def test_selenium_1(self):
        Testsss.selenium_test(self,1)

    def test_selenium_2(self):
        Testsss.selenium_test(self, 2)

    def test_selenium_3(self):
        Testsss.selenium_test(self, 3)

    def test_selenium_4(self):
        Testsss.selenium_test(self, 4)        

    def test_selenium_5(self):
        Testsss.selenium_test(self, 5)        

    def test_selenium_6(self):
        Testsss.selenium_test(self, 6)        

    def test_selenium_7(self):
        Testsss.selenium_test(self, 7)        

    def test_selenium_8(self):
        Testsss.selenium_test(self, 8)        

    def test_selenium_9(self):
        Testsss.selenium_test(self, 9)        

    def test_selenium_10(self):
        Testsss.selenium_test(self, 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running this on Linux you could use the `top` shell command to view the running processes. When open, if you press `Shift-H` it will show you the threads. Run the program whilst watching `top`, and you should see several python threads running under one parent thread. If so, it's working.

Comment: Thanks mate, I did not think about testing it this way :)